# How to connect with difference Ip address

Tags: java

My server have many ipaddress (a full /30 block)
how to  make socket with other ipaddress than default ip address

```
Socket socket = new Socket()
```

Comment: Are you trying to listen on different ip addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Use one the alternative constructors

e.g. [Socket(java.net.InetAddress, int port)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.net.InetAddress,%20int))

For a server wishing to use a specific ip address and port, you should be using [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html)

Use [bind(java.net.SocketAddress)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#bind(java.net.SocketAddress)) to specify the local ip address and port.

Comment: I want to make outgoing socket , and want to client using diffrence    ipaddress .